# Permission denied when trying to open /proc file from user space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to open a proc file from user space so I can write to it but when I open it I get `Permission denied`.  Below is how I'm creating the proc file.  I've tried messing around with the permissions but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
struct proc_dir_entry procDir = NULL;
struct proc_dir_entry infofile = NULL;

static struct seq_operations seqOps = {
    .start  = seqStart,
    .next   = seqNext,
    .stop   = seqStop,
    .show   = seqShow
};

static int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *fp)
{
    return seq_open(fp, &seqOps);
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .open           = open,
    .read           = read,
    .write          = write,
    .llseek         = lseek,
    .release        = single_release,
};

static int __init app_init(void)
{
procDir = proc_mkdir("app", NULL);

infofile = proc_create("info", 0, procDir, &fops);
//infofile = proc_create("info", 777, procDir, &fops);  // also tried this
}
```

Below is how I'm trying to opening it from the user space side.

```
fopen("/proc/app/info", "wb+");
```

The modules loads fine and when I run `ls /proc/app/` the proc file structure is there.  Thanks and any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does `ls -l /proc/app/info` report?  Which user account  is trying to do this?

Comment: Note: `777` is not `0777`.